# Adding another role in form based authentication

Tags: jsp, authorization, web.xml, roles

I am a beginner learning form based authentication. So far I have my "admin" user/role and it works perfectly, but now I want to add another role with limited privileges. I have searched online but the tutorials only have the admin role. Where would I add the role in the web.xml file?

Current `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description> An administrator </description>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Would I add another security-constraint and another security-role tag, or add to it, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another

`<security-constraint>` tag to specify a different protected area, as well as another

`<security-role>` to specify the role. See below:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Regular User Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>employee</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description> An administrator </description>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description> A regular user </description>
    <role-name>employee</role-name>
</security-role>
```